# Grafana Dashboard setup for Prometheus Federation

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

I am using prometheus federation to scrape metrics from multiple k8s cluster. It works ok and I would like to create some dashboard on grafana which I'd like to filter dashboards by tenant(cluster).. I am trying to use variables but the things that I do not understand, even if ı did not specify something special for `kube_pod_container_status_restars_total`,it contains the label that I specied below static_configs but `kube_node_spec_unschedulable` is not.

So where this differences come from and what should I do ? Meanwhile what is the best practice way to setup a dashboard which can provide dashboard filter by multiple cluster name? should ı use relabel?

```
kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{app="kube-state-metrics",container="backup",....,tenant="022"}
```

---

```
kube_node_spec_unschedulable{app="kube-state-metrics",....kubernetes_pod_name="kube-state-metrics-7d54b595f-r6m9k",node="022-kube-master01",pod_template_hash="7d54b595f"
```

---

**Prometheus Server**

```
prometheus.yml:
  rule_files:
    - /etc/config/rules
    - /etc/config/alerts

  scrape_configs:
    - job_name: prometheus
      static_configs:
        - targets:
          - localhost:9090
```

---

**Central Cluster**

```
  scrape_configs:
    - job_name: federation_012
      scrape_interval: 5m
      scrape_timeout: 1m

      honor_labels: true
      honor_timestamps: true
      metrics_path: /prometheus/federate

      params:
        'match[]':
          - '{job!=""}'
      scheme: https

      static_configs:
        - targets:
          - host
          labels:
            tenant: 012

      tls_config:
        insecure_skip_verify: true

    - job_name: federation_022
      scrape_interval: 5m
      scrape_timeout: 1m

      honor_labels: true
      honor_timestamps: true
      metrics_path: /prometheus/federate

      params:
        'match[]':
          - '{job!=""}'
      scheme: https

      static_configs:
        - targets:
          - host
          labels:
            tenant: 022

      tls_config:
        insecure_skip_verify: true
```

Comment: probably you need to try `honor_labels=true`. In case it does not affect the labels try `relabel_configs`. https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config

Comment: @dmkvl I've already honor_labels_true.. Where and how should ı add this relabel_configs?

Comment: I don't see it in your scrape_configs, could you share your full/updated scrape_configs?

Comment: @dmkvl, ı added whole  in answer.. should ı need to add relabel_configs in each prometheus server or for the federation one ? And how should add to differentiate to tenant name?

Comment: I posted an answer with the possible `federate` and `source/tenant` scrape jobs configs. I suppose this should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Central Prometheus server**

```
  scrape_configs:
    - job_name: federate
      scrape_interval: 5m
      scrape_timeout: 1m

      honor_labels: true
      honor_timestamps: true
      metrics_path: /prometheus/federate

      params:
        'match[]':
          - '{job!=""}'
      scheme: https

      static_configs:
        - targets:
          - source_host_012
          - source_host_022

      tls_config:
        insecure_skip_verify: true
```

**Source Prometheus (tenant 012)**

```
prometheus.yml:
  rule_files:
    - /etc/config/rules
    - /etc/config/alerts

  scrape_configs:
    - job_name: tenant_012
      static_configs:
        - targets:
          - localhost:9090
          labels:
            tenant: 012
```

**Source Prometheus (tenant 022)**

```
prometheus.yml:
  rule_files:
    - /etc/config/rules
    - /etc/config/alerts

  scrape_configs:
    - job_name: tenant_022
      static_configs:
        - targets:
          - localhost:9090
          labels:
            tenant: 022
```

If you still don't get needed labels, try to add `relabel_configs` to you `federate` job and try to differentiate metrics by a source job name:

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [job]
    target_label: tenant
```

or extract distinctive information from the `__address__` (or from any other __ prefixed) label for example.

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    target_label: tenant_host
```

PS: keep in mind that labels starting with __ will be removed from the label set after target relabeling is completed.

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config

Comment: ı will try and let you know the results but per my understanding ı need to add relabel_configs for federated job right not for source prometheus?

Comment: first try to configure source prometheus servers as in the example above, it seems that it will work without `relabel_configs`

Comment: ı follow your instructions but it wont work.. Now  kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total also do not have the tenant label

Comment: So give an example of your `kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total` metric with labels

Comment: 'kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{app="kube-state-metrics",container="backup",job="kubernetes-pods",kubernetes_io_hostname="022-kube-master01",kubernetes_namespace="kube-system",kubernetes_pod_name="kube-state-metrics-7d54b595f-r6m9k",namespace="database",node="022-kube-master01",pod="postgresql-postgresql-helm-backup-1587686400-7mczw",pod_template_hash="7d54b595f",ready="true"}'

Comment: @semural, you could extract the tenant id/name from the labels `kubernetes_io_hostname` or `node`